# white space appear after call phonegap camera function

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

In my app, everytime when I call the camera ( either take a picture or scan barcode), there will be a white space added to the bottom(tested on ios 7). It can grow by how many times I used the camera. Looks like the same height of the status bar.

The camera is just using native SDK, nothing else in the code.

```
CameraHelper.prototype.takeCameraImage = function(callback){
console.log("takeCameraImage");

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {    quality: 49, 
                                                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                                                    correctOrientation: true,
                                                    targetWidth: 266,
                                                    targetHeight: 266
                                                });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    callback({imageURI: imageURI});
}
function onFail(message) {
    callback({message: message});
}

};
```

what's the possible reason for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, put this code in your MainViewController.m class

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) // iOS 7 or above
    {
        CGFloat top = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
        if(self.webView.frame.origin.y == 0){
            // We only want to do this once, or if the view has somehow been "restored" by other code.
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y + top, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height - top);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like this codes not only fixed the gap issue, but also fixed the view in ios7 under status bar issue...

Comment: so, your problem fixed?

Comment: previouly, I used this code to make view under status bar: // iOS7 work around views below status bars
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }

Comment: I think this caused this problem... I delete this code and only use code you posted, and gap issue gone, also status bar been fixed

Comment: could you explain what exactly this codes does? I am interested

Comment: this one only to fix your status bar at the top of your app,not bottom because it push your view page from up side down.

Answer (score 0):

For the height try using self.view.frame.size.height - 20 (or what the status bar height is).

Comment: the problem is, there has no control of frame height when call this camera, where could I add this height to?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on a cordorva app running on an iPhone on OS 7.1. It happens on calls to inAppBrowser, as well. None of the solutions suggested here worked for me.

However, what did work was to find this in MainViewController.m (starting on line 78 for me):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment out the following line:

```
viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
```

That fixed the compounding white space issue for me completely and I found no negative consequences.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 static int score = 0;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
// View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
// you can do so here.

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
    viewBounds.origin.y = 10;
    //viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
    if (score==0) {
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
        score=1;
    }
    self.webView.frame = viewBounds;


}

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```